# SQL Server 2008R2 - Intellisense making it difficult to type the word "and"

Tags: sql-server, intellisense

I have Intellisense turned on in SQL Server 2008R2. The List Members that drives the auto-complete contains a list of all the SQL Server users. Which is where I run into a problem. There are a couple of users with logins of "andrew" and "AndrewL".

So what this means is that when I'm coding, if I type the word "and" - not an uncommon word to be using in SQL coding - auto complete will try to turn that into "andrew". I'm usually typing so fast I don't notice, but of course, as soon as it displays the word "andrew" and I hit the space bar, it fills in the word "andrew" and I then have to stop and backspace it out.

Is there any way I can stop this happening without turning off Intellisense all together? Either modifying the List Members not to include user names? I had a hunt around on the internet, but couldn't see anything that obviously suggested a fix.

Comment: This is a default behavior. Check free addin - https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/